# Interesting graph theory question

Tags: graph-theory

Is there any graph(without edges that has same beginning and end point, and without parallel edges), which has half amount of vertices than its dual graph?

My answer is no, since territories can only be polygons, and this graph should have x2 amounts of polygons than vertices, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Assume that there exists such planar graph with $V$ vertices, $E$ edges and $F$ faces with $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_F$ sides respectively. As the graph has no loops or multiple edges, then $f_i \geqslant 3$ for $i=1, 2, \ldots, F$. Therefore 
$$2E = \sum_{i=1}^Ff_i \geqslant 3F,$$

so $E \geqslant \frac{3}{2}F$. Now this and Euler formula for planar graphs give us $V = E - F + 2 > E - F \geqslant \frac{3}{2} F - F = \frac{1}{2}F$, which means that the graph has more than half as much vertices as the dual graph.